# Comparing floats in array using compare: selector

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa

I have an application which retrieves a lot of numerical data from a server and saves it into a `NSMUtableArray`. Now the values are floats which look like 10.0; 11.2; 30.003; 109.23, etc.

Now I used the `sortUsingSelector(@selector(compare:))` method to sort my array to find the largest and the smallest value. My output is following:

10.0
109.23
11.2
30.003

Now I suppose the compare: selector treats the values as strings and orders them accordingly. But thats not what I want. I want the values to be ordered according to their float value.
So my question is: Is there any way to sort the floats array according to their numerical value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be a short cut for the comparison, and there's no error checking, but something like this should do the trick:

```
NSArray* sorted = [unsorted sortedArrayWithOptions:0 usingComparator:^(id v1, id v2) {
  float f1 = [v1 floatValue];
  float f2 = [v2 floatValue];

  if (f1 == f2) return NSOrderedSame;
  return (f1 < f2) ? NSOrderedAscending : NSOrderedDescending;
}];
```

Or you could just store the values as `NSNumber` as they come in.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! The using comparator method worked out for me like a charme!

Comment: Your real problem is that you are storing the values as strings. If you store them as NSNumber objects then you can simply use the compare: method like you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

You should store them as `NSNumber`s instead of `NSStrings`. Where you are currently adding to your array, do this instead:

```
[myArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:incomingFloat]];
```

Now the compare selector will sort in numeric order.